# Does this code work when comparing a floating point number to a string?

Tags: javascript

I was reading code in a library from Adobe (snap.svg.js) and I saw this code, which confused me:

```
function curveDim(p1x, p1y, c1x, c1y, c2x, c2y, p2x, p2y) {
    var a = (c2x - 2 * c1x + p1x) - (p2x - 2 * c2x + c1x),
        b = 2 * (c1x - p1x) - 2 * (c2x - c1x),
        c = p1x - c1x,
        t1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a,
        t2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 / a;
    Math.abs(t1) > "1e12" && (t1 = .5);
    Math.abs(t2) > "1e12" && (t2 = .5);
```

Since the formula is pretty complicated, I couldn't come up with values to test it, so I wanted to ask the general question: why can you compare Math.abs(t1) to a string '1e12'? Wouldn't that convert the floating point number to a string and then just do lexical comparison? What if the variable a is zero? Is this good code? Any explanation of what the author is trying to do and if it is correct would be great.

Comment: "1e12" is shorthand exponent, equivalent to 1000000000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `>` operator converts both operands to numbers (http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.2, http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5).

See what happens when I convert the string to a number:

```
> +"1e12"
1000000000000
```

[`1e12` is actually a valid number literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Floating-point_literals) and means *1 * 10<sup>12</sup>*. No idea why they used strings instead, `Math.abs(t1) > 1e12` would work just as fine.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Also I can't doubt your 212k reputation :)

Comment: @bits: Always doubt! People make mistakes :) But you can trust the specification ;) You're welcome!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the ECMAScript link which indicates that it is valid code. I also have no idea why they used strings.

Comment: I think because people like us would be even more confused if it wasn't string.

Comment: if i had to take a random stab in the dark, i'd say maybe to prevent incorrect parsing from a minifier script

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test this yourself

```
var t1 = 10000000000000;
if (Math.abs(t1) > "1e12")
    console.log('t1 is greater');
else
    console.log('t1 is less or equal');
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gg7s6/)

Comment: Got it, as Felix explained, javascript converts "1e12" to number because it is one of operands of `>`.

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Yes, the test proves it is correct. The answer by Felix tells me why.